# How to change Ubuntu network setting by editing/creating config file?

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, ethernet

In Ubuntu 20.04 desktop, there is a GUI network tool in `All Settings` -> `Network`.

If I set a static IP to some network adapter, there will be a config file generated in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

But the file is generated by GUI only if it's configured before. If I only have ssh access to a Ubuntu, how to set a static IP to another network adapter?

the config file is like:

```
[connection]
id=Wired connection 1
uuid=e5b1ad45-b127-3590-bfd3-99a4c39c9c16
type=ethernet
autoconnect-priority=-999
interface-name=eno1
permissions=
timestamp=1629423741

[ethernet]
mac-address-blacklist=

[ipv4]
address1=192.168.1.30/16,192.168.1.1
dns=192.168.1.1;
dns-search=
ignore-auto-dns=true
method=manual

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto

[proxy]
```

If I copy the config file, which part should I change?
I guess I need to change `interface-name=eno1` at least, should I also change `uuid` and `id`? Is `uuid` any random uuid?

In some device, I also see `mac` address in the config file (to my surprise, this config file does not have it), if `mac` is present, should I also put the same mac as I get from `ifconfig`?

Comment: see `nmcli` for the command line equivalent https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html

Comment: Or `nmtui` maybe an option too.

Answer (score 2):

`nmtui` is the tool I wish I had known a month ago, which is actually already installed in my remote Ubuntu.

Comment: I also wish all gnome GUI operations have companying text based ui like nmtui (maybe it's already the truth?) so that I only need ssh and will never need a software like remote vnc.